# How to tell Git to use a different SSH config file?

Tags: linux, ssh, git

I want to specify a lot of options for SSH when Git uses it. We're using ISPConfig, which sets the owner of the web users' home directory to `root`, which causes a lot of trouble, including that I can't set any SSH configuration. Setting the `$HOME` variable doesn't work either. I have to craft my `git` commands to use a different SSH config file. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set environment variables, I would first try something like

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F /path/to/config"
```

However this will only work with Git 2.3+. Assuming you're on an older version, you'll need something slightly more involved:

```
echo "ssh -F /path/to/config-file" > /some/path/git-ssh-wrapper
chmod +x /some/path/git-ssh-wrapper
export GIT_SSH="/some/path/git-ssh-wrapper"
```

This is because (from git man page):

> To pass options to the program that you want to list in GIT_SSH you will need to wrap the program and options into a shell script, then set GIT_SSH to refer to the shell script

Comment: Does that mean the `/some/path/git-ssh-wrapper` will need `chmod +x`?

Comment: Good point - yes it will. Edited.